# Depth sorting issues

Tags: sorting, pixi.js

ll be quick.

I have a ground area with mulitple `sprites` on, and some of have to be ordered and i'm doing it with `zIndex` and also, i have an avatar that can go behind or in front of some `sprites` and i know that would be better to sort them by `a.y - b.y`; but i can't use both because it being conflicted any idea how should i structure it.

Used `(PIXI.Container().sortableChildren = true and add zIndex)`

Used `(PIXI.Container().children.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y`

Expecting to find a way to use one of these method to fix depth sort.